# Не получается обработать данные Ajax запроса

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

Только изучаю js и не понимаю пока почему не получается обработать данные. Есть список объектов, при клике на какой либо объект мне приходит в `console.log` свойство этого объекта (либо 1 либо 0). Так вот не получается обработать данные с таки условием, что бы при 1 показывался блок в форме а при 0 нет. Вот скрипт:

```js
<?
$arSelect = Array("ID", "IBLOCK_ID", "NAME", "PROPERTY_NEED_OSAGO");
$arFilter = Array("IBLOCK_ID" => "3", "ACTIVE" => "Y", "ID"=> $_POST["99999company"]);
$res = CIBlockElement::GetList(Array(), $arFilter, false, Array("nPageSize" => 300), $arSelect);
while ($ob = $res->Fetch()) {
    $result[] = $ob["PROPERTY_NEED_OSAGO_VALUE"];
}
if($result[0]["PROPERTY_NEED_OSAGO_VALUE"] == "1"){

    $response = array('result'=>'success');
    result($response);
}else{
    $response = array('result'=>'fail');
    result($response);
}
```

```js
    $( ".form-controlre" ).change(function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: 'phpOsago.php',
            data: $('.passegAdd').serialize(),
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (result) {
                if(result === "success") {
                    console.log(result);

                document.getElementById("blok").style.visibility = "visible";
                //json.encode JSON.PARSE
            }else{
                    document.getElementById("blok").style.visibility = "hidden";
                }
            }

        });
        return true;
    });
```

Comment: Покажите, что делает функция result.

Comment: @AlexanderSemikashev я так понял что эта функция записывает массив со значением либо success либо fail

Comment: Так вы покажите код.

Comment: `console.log(result)` случайно не такое выкатывает ? `{"result":"success"}`

Comment: Если да, то меняй условие на `if(result.result === "success")`

Comment: И я очень надеюсь, что функция `result` в php коде, просто рендерит json

Comment: @dev_null мне консоль лог ничего выдает в таком формате `{"result":"success"}` выдает только когда `echo $result[0]["PROPERTY_NEED_OSAGO_VALUE"];` ставлю

Comment: Так дело в том что и нужно в php коде распечатать результат, чтоб js получил какие то данные. `echo json_encode('success')` после `result($response);`

Comment: @dev_null можете накидать простенький пример, если вас не затруднит?

Comment: Что у вас в функции `result()`? какие данные выводит php-скрипт?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**PHP:**

```
<?php
$response = array('result'=>'success');
echo json_encode($response));
```

---

**Кусок из вашего AJAX:**

```
...
dataType: 'json',
success: function (data) {
    json = JSON.parse(data);

    if (json.result == 'success') {
        document.getElementById("blok").style.visibility = "visible";
    } else {
        document.getElementById("blok").style.visibility = "hidden";
    }
}
...
```

После `success` никаких `else`.

Comment: записал переменную по другому `$response = '{"result": "success"}';` а то ошибка записи json была и в консоле увидел то что нужно `result: success`

Answer (score 1):

```
$arSelect = Array("ID", "IBLOCK_ID", "NAME", "PROPERTY_NEED_OSAGO");
$arFilter = Array("IBLOCK_ID" => "3", "ACTIVE" => "Y", "ID"=> $_POST["99999company"]);
$res = CIBlockElement::GetList(Array(), $arFilter, false, Array("nPageSize" => 300), $arSelect);
while ($ob = $res->Fetch()) {
    $result[] = $ob["PROPERTY_NEED_OSAGO_VALUE"];
}
if($result[0]["PROPERTY_NEED_OSAGO_VALUE"] == "1"){

    $response = array('result'=>'success');
    result($response);
    echo json_encode('success);
}else{
    $response = array('result'=>'fail');
    result($response);
    echo json_encode('fail');
}
```

Comment: забыли добавить `exit` после `echo json_encode('success);`

Comment: @dev_null спасибо большое!!!